# Move data between workbooks and save as new (Repeat process for every workbook in a folder)

Tags: vba, excel

How can I move certain data from one workbook (`wb1`) to another workbook (`wb_template`) and **save it as a new workbook** with a new name extension “`_new`” (eg., `wb1_new.xlsx`)?

I need to able to repeat this process automatically **for every workbook in a specific folder**.

Here is a screenshot of the process I have in mind: 
[image: img]

My code works only between two workbooks so far and there is no new Excel file created:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb_template As Workbook
    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\PlutoX\Desktop\Folder\wb1")
    Set wb_template = Application.Workbooks.Open _
                                ("C:\Users\PlutoX\Desktop\Folder\wb_template")
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = _
        wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = _
        wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = _
        wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
    wb1.Close False
    wb_template.Close True
End Sub
```

Comment: So are those the only operations that happen between the source and template?

Comment: You will need to loop through each workbook in the specific folder, open the workbook and perform your actions for each workbook. You can do a Google search for "excel vba loop through all workbooks in folder and copy range"